# How to set trading session time in Tradingview for Strategy backtesting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

In tradingview the USDINR chart has data for almost 24 hours, but the Indian currency market is open only from 9 AM IST till 4:30 PM IST. So, for backtesting only these candles are relevant to me. How can make the strategy script to consider candles only between this time?

Comment: So in another words, you want your code to run between those hours only?

Comment: Yes, I want the pinescript code to consider the candles between that time only for entry and exit. I tried with sessiontime but still buy/sell signals are getting generated outside of that time.